# CodeIgniter style $this->modelname->function() calls

Tags: php, classloader

What I'm trying to do is access models in the CodeIgniter style, by calling `$this->model_name->function()` in my controllers. heres what I've done so far:

```
$this->load = new Load();

    foreach (glob("application/models/*.php") as $file) {
        $model = basename($file, ".php");
        $this->$model = new $model;
    }
```

I know I can't do what I tried there, but hopefully you can see my objective. What I want to do is make PHP write `$this->modelname = new modelname;` for each file in the model folder. I'm grabbing all the PHP files and stripping the directory and .php to leave just the file name.

I apologize if this is hard to understand, its hard to explain >.<

Answer (score 1):

It actually should work, you just need to actually include the file:

```
foreach (glob("application/models/*.php") as $file) {
    @include_once $file;
    $model = basename($file, ".php");
    if (class_exists($model)) {
        $this->$model = new $model;
    } else {
        //handle error, trow an exception?
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that! Thats what happens when you write code at 3am I guess. Works now, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an autoloader?

```
spl_autoload_register('customAutoloader');

function customAutoloader($class_name){
    $file_name = $class_name . ".php";
    //Model
    if(substr($class_name, -5) === "Model"){
        if(is_readable(PATH_MODELS . $file_name)){
            require_once(PATH_MODELS . $file_name);
        }
    }
}
```

In this situation, all model classes must be called ModelnameModel, and files should be named the same - ModelnameModel.php and be located in PATH_MODELS.